# How to derive the worst case time complexity of Heapify algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, heap, heapsort

I would like to know how to derive the time complexity for the Heapify Algorithm for Heap Data Structure.

I am asking this question in the light of the book "Fundamentals of Computer Algorithms" by Ellis Horowits. I am adding some screenshots of the algorithm as well as the derivation given in the book.

Algorithm:

[image]

[image]

Derivation for worst case complexity:

[image]

I understood the first part and last part of this calculation but I cannot figure out how `2^(i-1) x (k-i)` changed into `i2^(k-i-1)`.

All the derivations I can find in the internet takes a different approach by considering the height of the tree differently. I know that approach also leads to the same answer but I would like to know about this approach.

You might need the following information:

`2^k-1 = n` or approximately `2^k = n`, where k is the number of levels, starting from the root node and the level of root is 1 (not 0) and n is the number of nodes.

Also the worst case time complexity of the `Adjust()` function is proportional to the height of the sub-tree it is called, that is O(log n, where n is the total number of elements in the sub-tree.

Comment: Shouldn't this belong to Computer Science Stack Exchange?

Comment: oh ok, I will ask the question there.

Comment: I have asked this same question on cs stackoverflow. But I cannot delete this post. Is this fine having duplicate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variable substitution.

First, realize that in the leftmost side of the equation, the last term of the sum is zero (because when `i = k`, `k-i = 0`). So, the range of the first summation can be written as `1 <= i <= k-1`. Now, substitute `i` with `k-i`. `i` iterates over the set `{1, 2, ... , k-1}` and `k-i` iterates over the set `{k-1, ... 2, 1}`, they are the same set, therefore, we can do this substitution.